# How to fix import / no-unresolved eslint to look at package.json "module" instead of "main"

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, eslint

I'm currently importing a yarn workspace package that has the `module` field defined in ES6 and linting with the plugin `eslint-plugin-import`

My create-react-app setup automatically uses the `module` through webpack but eslint is complaining that `@mycompany/utils` package is undefined.

`Unable to resolve path to module '@mycompany/utils'. [import/no-unresolved]`

> So my question is how do I get my linter to look at the `module` path instead of `main`

This is my package.json for the utils package

```
{
  "name": "@mycompany/utils",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "src/index.js"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - install **eslint-import-resolver-webpack** as a dev-dependency
>     https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/tree/master/resolvers/webpack
> - Update your settings in your .eslintrc

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:import/recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended"
  ],
  "plugins": ["react"],

  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "webpack": {
        "config": {
          "resolve": {
            "modules": ["node_modules"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What this does is that it updates your `eslint-plugin-import` to resolve using `webpack` instead of `node`. In the webpack resolver it'll automatically look at your `module` over `main` first.

https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/resolvers/webpack/index.js#L200